# Illegal indirection when multiplicating

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm starting to learn C++. Here is a problem that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define PI 3.14;

int main(){
    double r = 5.0;
    double circle;
    double inp;

    circle = 2 * PI * r;
    cout << circle;
    cin >> inp;
}
```

It shows error: `error C2100: illegal indirection`.
I've googled but found no answer. Thanks

Comment: Best policy is to stop using #define

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, i'm following tutorials..

Comment: Make it a goal to avoid #define if humanly possible. That policy will serve you well.

Comment: mistakes can make good lessons. 
btw, anyone who uses macros gets weird error messages from time to time. Typos (and small cognitive errors) tend to show up differently than similar mistakes in regular code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#define PI 3.14;
```

The `;` is wrong, delete it.

btw, your line expands to `circle = 2 * 3.14;  * r;` 
So the compiler is then complaining about the *r, which explains the error message.

Comment: Better still, change it to `const double PI = 3.14;`. Unnecessary macros are a bad idea, even if you do manage to avoid all their syntactic deathtraps.

Answer (score 6):

Macros are (relatively) simple substitutions so, when you write:

```
#define PI 3.14;
circle = 2 * PI * r;
```

it actually ends up as:

```
circle = 2 * 3.14; * r;
```

effectively the *two* statements:

```
circle = 2 * 3.14;
* r;
```

That last line would be a perfectly valid expression (albeit it not a very useful one) if `r` were a pointer of some description. However, given it's a double, that's where you're getting the illegal indirection from.

The use of macros is something you should generally avoid nowadays except in very specific circumstances. The use of them to provide inline functions has been subsumed mostly by the `inline` keyword ("mostly", because the `inline` keyword is only a suggestion).

In addition, using it to provide constants can be better done (with the advantage of full type support and usually better debugging) with the `const` keyword.

In other words, your `PI` constant would be better written as something like:

```
const double PI = 3.141592653589;
```

Just about the only place I use the pre-processor nowadays is for conditional compilation.

---

As an aside, you probably meant `circumference` rather than `circle`. The former is the length around the outside of the circle, the latter isn't really a length value at all.